# django runserver : relation "django_migrations" already exists

Tags: django

I have a django project source code, which includes several apps. The source code have been run successfully on one environment, but when transplanted to another device, with the same postgresql version(9.4.4), python version(2.7.5), and django version(1.8.5), but the runserver reports errors like this. The database has been imported in advance.

```
return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "django_migrations" already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this `python manage.py migrate --fake`

You can read more about it in [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake)

Answer (score 0):

Try troubleshooting Initial migrations using --fake-initial

```
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-option---fake-initial

Answer (score 0):

**If you have an empty database you can clear all your migrations and then again run migrations and migrate command.**

```
python manage.py makemigrations

python manage.py migrate
```